# Accesing the parent __init__ variable to Child Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Hello im trying to make a oop function but im currently stuck on how can i inherit the `__init__` arguments of my parent class to the child class, is there a method that can i use to adapt the variable from my main to use in child?

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
class b(a):
    def __init__(self, age):
        super().__init__()
        self.age = age
```

When i trying to use the `name` from the parent it errors.

```
b('joe', 40)

> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given>
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments from the child constructor need to be passed to the parent. This is because the child constructor *overrides* the method (i.e. replaces the constructor method) from the parent. Calling `super` allows you to access the original parent constructor, which will need to be provided the appropriate arguments.

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
class b(a):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.age = age
```

As you might notice, this means you need to write a lot of boilerplate code to plumb down the arguments (especially if there are many arguments). If this class is purely for data, then dataclasses provide a much easier and less error prone alternative.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class a:
    name: str

@dataclass
class b(a):
    age: int

print(b('joe', 12))
```

```
b(name='joe', age=12)
```